# Can't use method from another class?

Tags: java, bluej

I know there are other threads that have a similar title, but I have done everything that was suggested in those threads.

I am attempting to make a dinosaur racing game called Fossil Fuels, for now I am creating the generic game with obstacles floating down from the top which need to be avoided.

I do know Python, and have only recently begun learning Java, so this question probably sounds stupid, but here goes.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.lang.System;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Math;
public class MainLoop
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        boolean mloop = true;
        int obsMoveIncrease = 1;
        ArrayList obsList = new ArrayList();
        final String[] validObsTypes = {"tree", "rock", "bush"};
        long moveFrequency = 750;
        long beginningTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long obsInterval = 3000; //how often a new object is created in milliseconds
        long timeOfLastMove = System.currentTimeMillis();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("background.jpg"); //background is 700 by 1500 px
        JLabel bgLabel = new JLabel(background);
        frame.add(bgLabel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        while (mloop)
        {
            int freshObsTypeNum = (int) Math.random() * 3;
            String freshObsType = validObsTypes[freshObsTypeNum]; //chooses a pseudo-random valid obstacle type
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= beginningTime + obsInterval) 
            { //checks if sufficient time has passed since last obstacle was created
                Obstacle obs = new Obstacle(freshObsType, 0);
                obsList.add(0, obs);
                beginningTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //resets "clock"
            }


            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= timeOfLastMove + moveFrequency) //checks if it is time to move obstacles
            {
                timeOfLastMove = System.currentTimeMillis();
                for (int i = 0; i < obsList.size(); i++)
                {
                    obsList.get(i).moveObs(obsMoveIncrease); //moves obstacles ERROR OCCURS ON moveObs
                    if (obsList.get(i).getObsY() > 1500)
                    {
                        obsList.remove(i);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my obstacle class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
public class Obstacle
{
    private String obstacleType;
    private int obstacleXPos;
    public final int[] obsXlist = {0, 175, 350, 525}; //list of starting positions (4 slots along the x axis)
    int obstacleYPos = 0;
    public Obstacle(String type, int startPos)
    {
        obstacleType = type;
        obstacleXPos = obsXlist[startPos];
    }

    public int getObsX()
    {return obstacleXPos;}

    public int getObsY()
    {return obstacleYPos;}

    public void moveObs(int increase)
    {obstacleYPos += increase;}

    ImageIcon obstacleImg;
    public JLabel getObsImg() //gets image (on a label) for keyword given to constructor
    {
        if (obstacleType.equals("tree"))
            obstacleImg = new ImageIcon("treeObs.jpg");
        else if (obstacleType.equals("rock"))
            obstacleImg = new ImageIcon("rockObs.jpg");
        else if (obstacleType.equals("bush"))
            obstacleImg = new ImageIcon("bushObs.jpg");
        else
            System.out.println(obstacleType + " is not a valid obstacle type");

        JLabel obsLabel = new JLabel(obstacleImg);
        return obsLabel;
    }
}
```

It is telling me that the symbol cannot be found when I call moveObs(int) from within the main method. I don't know why I wouldn't have access to my public methods in the Obstacle class

Comment: Try doing something like `ArrayList<Obstacle> obsList` so that the list knows what kind of things are inside so it knows what methods exist for those objects.

Comment: Just change your ArrayList definition to use generics like 
    ArrayList<Obstacle> obsList = new ArrayList<Obstacle>();

Comment: I just tried that, it solved the problem, but why did it work? Shouldn't it already know what type of items are in the list

Comment: Unrelated, but I would like to suggest you always use braces for your `if/else` blocks and to keep a consistent style for them as well. Check https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2970 for more on the topic.

Comment: You should use List<Obstacle> obsList = new ArrayList<>();.  Always use the interface if you can. Java did not always have generics so there are legacy classes that take in plain Objects which would not know about the Obstacle methods. Back then you would get the object then cast to Obstacle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

obsList does not have a type.
You are trying to call moveObs() on 'Object', not on 'Obstacle'.

To change that you need to make obsList a typed list like this:

```
ArrayList<Obstacle> obsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you, I was under the impression that it would know what type of object it was because I was using a method for obstacles, but I suppose I have to specify when creating the arraylist.

Comment: Yes, you added an Obstacle to obsList and it worked because Obstacle is also an Object (as is everything implicitly in Java).  While you can add a lot of other Objects and throw them in together, you can only call methods that ALL of them have in common, which are methods of the Object type, as defined when you created obsList ('new ArrayList()' is implicitly 'new ArrayList<Object>()'). So you always specify the type.